# Adding text to Twitter Tweet text area

Tags: javascript, twitter

How can I add text to the text area in the new tab that opens when I hit the "tweet button" (twitter.com/intent/tweet) using JavaScript? This problem has happened to me while doing my Random Quote Machine project in CodeCamp. I have tried things related to the data-text attribute but didn`t work.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When asking a question, it's important to include all the code necessary to understand the problem, and to include it here in the question and not just via a link to some off-site resource.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should put the text in the href link button (see the twitter API):

```
href='https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?hashtags=quote&text="I begin by taking. I shall find scholars later to demonstrate my perfect right.", Frederick (II) the Great'
```